# How to convert list generated from JSON file into a dataframe and retain all needed columns?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am attempting to load in a JSON file which contains the data I need for my script. It wasn't always done in JSON so I never had to load one in before so I'm a bit lost in what is happening.

I got some errors and after finding solutions here on StackOverflow, I have now found a way that does load in my `.JSON`:

```
data = [json.loads(line) for line in open('C:/filepath/data.json', 'r', encoding='utf8')]

#creates a list, but I need a dataframe

dataset = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`dataset` looks like this:

```
exp    username     email    date                        items
ema                         2_12_21_3_00_14 PM         [{'item 1': '29'}, {'item 2': '19'}, {'item 3': '27'}, {'item 4': '24'}, {'item 5': '39'}, {'item 6': '40'}, {'item 7': '43'}, {'item 8': '19'}, {'item 9': '19'}, {'item 10': '22'}, {'item 11': '35'}, {'item 12': '33'}, {'item 13': '23'}, {'item 14': '27'}, {'item 15': '28'}, {'item 16': '23'}, {'item 17': '26'}, {'item 18': '30'}, {'item 19': '29'}, {'item 20': '31'}, {'item 21': '35'}, {'item 22': '29'}]
```

The items are supposed to be separate columns with their own data each row. I'm not sure why this is happening. Is there any way I can retain those separate columns or convert this dataframe to get those columns?

SOME EXTRA INFO:
The errors I was getting before were `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte` and ```JSONDecodeError: Extra data````

That was just using the method

```
File = open('data.json')
dataset = json.load(File)
#charmap issue

File = open('data.json', encoding='utf8')
dataset = json.load(File)
#extra data issue
```

EDIT:
This is what `data` looks like before passing it through `pd.DataFrame`

```
Type  Size    Value
dict  5       {'exp':'ema', 'username':'','email':'', 'date':'2_12_21_3_00_14 PM', ...
```

For simplicity, I am showing only the first entry as my data goes on over 6,000 entries and printing the head in my script gets weird.

I can also click on the `Value` section, as it is a dictionary and it opens up into a table of elements with the same column names as `dataset` but in a horizontal orientation.

Comment: Can you edit to show what `data` looks like before you pass it to pd.DataFrame?

Comment: Done. I should add that ```data``` is loading in a list of dictionaries. I can confirm that ```pd.DataFrame.from_dict()``` does not work. I get the same dataframe as my current method using ```pd.DataFrame()```

Answer (score 0):

If I Understand Correctly:

You can try:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df.explode('items',ignore_index=True)
s=(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('items').tolist())
     .agg(sorted,key=pd.isnull).dropna().T
     .reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'items',0:'items value'}))
df=df.join(s)
```

output of `df`:

```
    exp     username    email   date                items   items value
0   ema     NaN         NaN     2_12_21_3_00_14 PM  item 1      29
1   ema     NaN         NaN     2_12_21_3_00_14 PM  item 2      19
2   ema     NaN         NaN     2_12_21_3_00_14 PM  item 3      27
3   ema     NaN         NaN     2_12_21_3_00_14 PM  item 4      24
4   ema     NaN         NaN     2_12_21_3_00_14 PM  item 5      39
    ...     ...         ...     ..................  ......  ..
19  ema     NaN         NaN     2_12_21_3_00_14 PM  item 20     31
20  ema     NaN         NaN     2_12_21_3_00_14 PM  item 21     35
21  ema     NaN         NaN     2_12_21_3_00_14 PM  item 22     29
```